# Android Studio could not find any version that matches come.google.maps

Tags: android, gradle, maps

My gradle seems to be complaining that it `Could not find any version that matches com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+`.

**Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    signingConfigs {
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/svg-android.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try excluding support library from maps utils `compile ('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }`

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I also noticed that no maps library is in my external libraries folder. But I guess that will be added once this is fixed?

Comment: Strange, this entry works in my project. Try also adding in your gradle build `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}`

Comment: If it doesn't work, download aar file from repositorty by yourself and put it in `libs` folder. For file name maps-utils.aar try adding this `repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'maps-utils', ext:'aar')
}`

Comment: I fixed it by reverting the gradle back to a previous version. Boom, it all works.

Answer (score 0):

you havn't declared a repository for your project, just for the buildscript stuff.

try adding a first level repository block

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```